# carry a variable from one sub up into the sub above it

Tags: vb.net

I am working with two sub routines.

the first one processes existing records. the second one shows real time updates of the first.

i want to correlate the incoming data in the second sub back to the first

I have tried using a public variable, but that does not seem to work.

in sub 2 i have incoming data:

```
dim lp as integer
lp = last_update 'the data fresh from the server updating in real time
```

now i want to take the info in 'lp' and use it in the sub just above it for data processing:

```
revised_data = lp
```

not sure how to do that

many thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest using a function and return lp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call the `Sub` above it with `lp` as one of the parameters:

```
Public Sub AboveSub(ByVal param1 as String) 'Or whatever lp is
    Dim revised_data as String = param1
End Sub
```

Then call it

```
AboveSub(lp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub FirstSub()
    dim lp as integer
    lp = last_update 'the data fresh from the server updating in real time
    SecondSub(lp) ' <-- this is the call to your second sub it passes `lp` in
End Sub

Public Sub SecondSub(lp_passed_in as integer)
    ' ...
    revised_data = lp_passed_in
    ' ...
End Sub
```